# What is your preference to accommodate Safari and Firefox users on MAC while implementing SharePoint 2010 Intranet Site?

Tags: macos, sharepoint, firefox

What is your preference to accommodate Safari and Firefox users on MAC while  implementing Intranet SharePoint 2010 Site for maximum user adoption on MAC?  Please see below for options

With following preferences a) Use AS IS Intranet zone and communicate to MAC users to use Safari b) Would you consider extending intranet zone to anonymous access accepting the disadvantages  c) Others

Please let me know your preferred strategy/solution or from your own SP 2010 Intranet implementation projects

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're looking at going anonymous, are the users external, non-employee, not on Active Directory users? If not, then don't go anonymous.

SharePoint 2010 treats Mac users as 2nd class citizens, it's a decent experience, but won't compare to IE on Windows. Custom designs can improve the Mac usability to a certain extent. Some functionality, datasheet view for example, requires IE to install ActiveX controls. Check out my blog post for some more details on browser support: http://davidlozzi.com/2012/04/17/sharepoint-browser-support-all-latest-browsers-supported-really/. Though targeted to browsers on Windows, I'd bet you'll see the same on Mac.

SharePoint 2013 makes great efforts towards playing nice with Mac (and other browsers). Maybe you should upgrade :-p.